# Thymeleaf table

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have problem table when i want set value with for each i.index get error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${i.index}". In Array i need numer so ${i.index} is int. I dont know what i do wrong.

```
<div class="form-group row" th:each="attribute, i: ${attributeList}">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" th:text="${attribute.name}"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{technicalAttributes[${i.index}].name}" class="form- 
            control" placeholder="Nazwa">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest expressions (`*{...${...}...}`) like you're doing without using preprocessing.  Your code should look like this:

```
<div class="form-group row" th:each="attribute, i: ${attributeList}">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" th:text="${attribute.name}"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{technicalAttributes[__${i.index}__].name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwa">
  </div>
</div>
```

(If you weren't using the th:field attribute, the expression `*{technicalAttributes[i.index].name}` would also be appropriate.  But since you are using a th:field you have to use preprocessing.)